# Using SOMEKEY+mousewheel for zoom in and out on vanilla UBUNTU 20.04 desktop?

Tags: 20.04, zooming, mouse-wheel

How to enable "mousewheel zooming" / "magnifying" on plain vanilla UBUNTU 20.04 Desktop (default desktop enviroment/system)??

I now searched the webs for >1h and yet still not found a solution, what i find suspicious.

i already use the "on board" desktop zoom feature which comes with UBUNTU Desktop 20.04, the one you can enable by SUPER+ALT+8 and i had modified the keybindings so i can zoom in and out using SUPER+ALT+'+' and SUPER+ALT+'-' . pretty good so far.

Now i would like to have it more "streamlined" so i can zoom in and out more easily/faster using the mousewheel (someKeys+mousewheel).

If there is no "neat direct" solution yet, i would also accept a solution which "maps" the keyboard+mousewheel "gesture" into a keyboard sequence (SUPER+ALT+'+/-'), to achieve more or less that.

But the "on board" keyboard shortcut UI seems not accepting mouse actions.

So... any tip how to achieve that with default UBUNTU 20.04 Desktop ?

Thanks
Axel

Comment: On my vanilla 20.04 pressing CTRL and advancing/retarding the mouse wheel to zoom in and out works fine in FF

Comment: im not talking about Firefox. im talking about UBUNTU DESKTOP. so the zoom works on ANY app!

Comment: Did you look at Zoom options in Settings? - Different solution but I'm only really trying to help so no need to shout at me!

Comment: I don't see "zoom" under the settings menu. ???